# Extract som info of xml file while keeping header lines/nodes

Tags: c#, .net, xml, winforms, visual-studio

I have an XML file which I want to extract some data from it. I have read all the [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=extract%20xml) regard this topic here as well as answers. But I want I want to have is keeping header while extracting some data. Would you please let me know your idea?

Here is the XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<pack version="3.5.6.4" appVersion="3.6j" language="Fa">
  <config>
    <radio name="Target" select="Linux" />
    <check name="Archive" checked="False" />
  </config>  
  <comment />
  <dialogs>
    <dialog name="FDE" used="True" process="Manual" interact="All">
      <check name="Backup" checked="True" locked="False" />
    </dialog>
    <dialog name="PDE" used="True" process="Automatic" interact="All">
      <check name="Backup" checked="False" locked="False" />
      <check name="Archive" checked="False" locked="False" />
    </dialog>
    <dialog name="TFSA" used="False" process="Manual" interact="All">
      <radio name="Mode" select="None" locked="False" />
    </dialog>
  </dialogs>
  <steps>
    <step name="1  INIT" checked="True" locked="False" collapsed="False" childs="Check" id="6">
      <hint />
    </step>
    <step name="2  Copy" checked="True" locked="False" collapsed="False" childs="Check" id="1">
      <hint />
      <step name="2.1  Copy Files to Card...." checked="True" locked="True" collapsed="False" childs="Check" id="5">
        <hint />        
      </step>
    </step>
  </steps>
</pack>
```

and what I want to have is keeping the first two lines(header) as:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<pack version="3.5.6.4" appVersion="3.6j" language="Fa">
  <steps>
    <step name="1  INIT" checked="True" locked="False" collapsed="False" childs="Check" id="6">
      <hint />
    </step>
    <step name="2  Copy" checked="True" locked="False" collapsed="False" childs="Check" id="1">
      <hint />
      <step name="2.1  Copy Files to Card...." checked="True" locked="True" collapsed="False" childs="Check" id="5">
        <hint />        
      </step>
    </step>
  </steps>
</pack>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try xml linq

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string xml =
                "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?>" +
                "<pack version=\"3.5.6.4\" appVersion=\"3.6j\" language=\"Fa\">" +
                  "<config>" +
                    "<radio name=\"Target\" select=\"Linux\" />" +
                    "<check name=\"Archive\" checked=\"False\" />" +
                  "</config>" +
                  "<comment />" +
                  "<dialogs>" +
                    "<dialog name=\"FDE\" used=\"True\" process=\"Manual\" interact=\"All\">" +
                      "<check name=\"Backup\" checked=\"True\" locked=\"False\" />" +
                    "</dialog>" +
                    "<dialog name=\"PDE\" used=\"True\" process=\"Automatic\" interact=\"All\">" +
                      "<check name=\"Backup\" checked=\"False\" locked=\"False\" />" +
                      "<check name=\"Archive\" checked=\"False\" locked=\"False\" />" +
                    "</dialog>" +
                    "<dialog name=\"TFSA\" used=\"False\" process=\"Manual\" interact=\"All\">" +
                      "<radio name=\"Mode\" select=\"None\" locked=\"False\" />" +
                    "</dialog>" +
                  "</dialogs>" +
                  "<steps>" +
                    "<step name=\"1  INIT\" checked=\"True\" locked=\"False\" collapsed=\"False\" childs=\"Check\" id=\"6\">" +
                      "<hint />" +
                    "</step>" +
                    "<step name=\"2  Copy\" checked=\"True\" locked=\"False\" collapsed=\"False\" childs=\"Check\" id=\"1\">" +
                      "<hint />" +
                      "<step name=\"2.1  Copy Files to Card....\" checked=\"True\" locked=\"True\" collapsed=\"False\" childs=\"Check\" id=\"5\">" +
                        "<hint />" +
                      "</step>" +
                    "</step>" +
                  "</steps>" +
                "</pack>";

            XDocument doc = XDocument.Parse(xml);

            XElement steps = doc.Descendants("steps").FirstOrDefault();
            XElement pack = doc.Element("pack");
            doc.Element("pack").ReplaceWith(new XElement("pack", new object[] {pack.Attributes(), steps}));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: And If one want to save it as a new file?

Comment: doc.Save("filename");

Comment: This duplicate all the `steps` nodes. The first copy is okay, but the second copy which is duplicate is converting all nodes to the same level.

Comment: I need to see your actual code.  The code I posted won't create duplicates  so I think the issue is the way you are using the code.